# How to get the number of elements present in sum function in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm want to get the number of elements present in sum function.
Example:

```
val counts = text.flatMap { _.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") }
      .map { (_, 1) }
      .keyBy(0)
      .timeWindow(Time.minutes(10))
      .sum(1)
```

output:

```
hello : 4
world : 2
foo : 8
my : 5
```

I want as output the number `4` that corresponds the number of elements.
I don't find any function like `count`

Answer (score 0):

The built-in aggregation functions are not very flexible. There are only `sum`, `min`, `max`, `minBy`, and `maxBy`. These only work on Tuple types and cannot be combined.

If you want to do anything beyond a single simple aggregate, you have to implement a custom `ReduceFunction` or `AggregateFunction`.
Another option is to have a look at the Table API or SQL which have support for group windows as well.